# How to compare each item in a variable to another item in the same variable in R?

Tags: r

I have a list in R with a series of dataframes. The dataframes represent individual datasets that have been coded by a number of different people. A very simplified version is as follows:

```
 file1 <- data.frame(coder=c("coder1", "coder1", "coder1", "coder1", 
                        "coder2","coder2",  "coder2", "coder2",
                        "anchor", "anchor", "anchor", "anchor"), 
                dur=c(120, 80, 60, 30, 257, 80, 55, 21, 130, 95, 60, 32))

 file2 <- data.frame(coder=c("coder1", "coder1", "coder1", "coder1", 
                        "coder2","coder2",  "coder2", "coder2",
                        "anchor", "anchor", "anchor", "anchor"),
                dur=c(130, 95, 60, 32, 123, 80, 62, 14, 257, 80, 55, 21))

 file3 <- data.frame(coder=c("coder1", "coder1", "coder1", "coder1", 
                        "coder2","coder2",  "coder2", "coder2",
                        "anchor", "anchor", "anchor", "anchor"),
                dur=c(32, 123, 80, 62, 130, 95, 60, 32, 123, 80, 62, 14))

 my_list <- list(file1, file2, file3)
```

I'm trying to create an output file that runs a correlation between `dur` values for each coder with those of an 'anchor' coder.

I want to generate some code that, for each element in the list, compares coders 1 and 2 with 'anchor' and then generates an r value for each coder in each file:

```
 cor_test_1_F1 <- cor.test(subset(file1, coder == "coder1")$dur, 
                      subset(file1, coder == "anchor")$dur, method = "spearman")

 cor_test_2_F1 <- cor.test(subset(file1, coder == "coder2")$dur, 
                      subset(file1, coder == "anchor")$dur, method = "spearman")
```

The output should be something like (values made up for simplicity):

```
 output <- tribble(~comparison, ~coder, ~r,
              "cor_test_F1", "coder1", 0.8,
              "cor_test_F1", "coder2", 0.78,
              "cor_test_F2", "coder1", 0.32,
              "cor_test_F2", "coder2", 0.41,
              "cor_test_F3", "coder1", 0.64,
              "cor_test_F3", "coder2", 0.57)
```

I can generate the r value no problem, but the issue I'm having is iterating through the coders to compare with the anchor coder. I have been attempting this using `lapply()` but perhaps a loop would be better.

Comment: If you have R > 4.3.0 you can use the function `SLR::multiple_tests`. This is a small package which you could install as `devtools::install_github('oonyambu/SLR')`

Comment: Thanks but this isn't really what I'm looking for - it's more about iterating through the coders than the test itself as I need to generate various kinds of data from the coder outputs.

Comment: The function will iterate and do the tests for the coders giving back a dataframe containing all the tests. ie `multiple_tests(dur~coder|file, df, cor.test)` should work

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
file1 <- data.frame(coder=c("coder1", "coder1", "coder1", "coder1", 
                            "coder2","coder2",  "coder2", "coder2",
                            "anchor", "anchor", "anchor", "anchor"), 
                    dur=c(120, 80, 60, 30, 257, 80, 55, 21, 130, 95, 60, 32))

file2 <- data.frame(coder=c("coder1", "coder1", "coder1", "coder1", 
                            "coder2","coder2",  "coder2", "coder2",
                            "anchor", "anchor", "anchor", "anchor"),
                    dur=c(130, 95, 60, 32, 123, 80, 62, 14, 257, 80, 55, 21))

file3 <- data.frame(coder=c("coder1", "coder1", "coder1", "coder1", 
                            "coder2","coder2",  "coder2", "coder2",
                            "anchor", "anchor", "anchor", "anchor"),
                    dur=c(32, 123, 80, 62, 130, 95, 60, 32, 123, 80, 62, 14))

my_list <- list(file1=file1,
                file2=file2,
                file3=file3)

# make a function that does what you want to do
do_test_on_source_low <- function(source, coderval) {
  test <- list(cor.test(subset(source, coder == coderval)$dur,
    subset(source, coder == "anchor")$dur,
    method = "spearman"
  ))
  names(test) <- coderval
  test
}

do_test_on_source <- function(source,sourcename){
  coder_vals <- unique(source$coder)
  coder_vals <- coder_vals[startsWith(coder_vals,"coder")]
  results <- lapply(coder_vals,\(x)do_test_on_source_low(source,x))
  tibble(results) |> unnest_longer(col = "results")  |> mutate(file=sourcename)
}


imap_dfr(my_list,
    do_test_on_source)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for the individual files but doesn't seem to give me the option to iterate through the coders as well. As well as iterating through the different files, I also want to compare coders 2, 3, 4, etc with the anchor.

Comment: edited the solution for all coders